# How can I remove the Navigation bar from a Navigation Based iPhone app?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am novice iPhone developer . I am developing a Navigation based app for iPhone. I don't use the Interface Builder in my app. I want to remove the Navigation Bar from the application.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` method in `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Some times I have encountered setNavigationBarHidden:animated doesn't work.. In this case you can try out self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;